# Caption below a figure when there is an equation next to that figure

Tags: equations, captions, minipage

I'm wondering how can I write the caption of a figure (which is next to an equation) only below the figure. The following code allows to write the caption on the right side of the figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{equation}
        f(x)=x^2
    \end{equation}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{myimage}
    \caption{\caption{Esempio di efficienza inversa nel caso di trasmissione meccanica con quattro stadi.}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `figure` instead of `SCfigure`.

Comment: Hello @JohnKormylo can you post an example please? I know how to use figure to add a figure with a caption below, but I don't know how to add also an equation next to the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tricky part is aligning the equation to the image, as opposed to the image plus caption.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{equation}
        f(x)=x^2
    \end{equation}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}% use first baseline
    \centering
    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{myimage}}
    \caption{Esempio di efficienza inversa nel caso di trasmissione meccanica con quattro stadi.}
  \end{minipage}%
  %\llap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}% show baseline
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @JohnKormylo thank you very much for your useful answer.